Error with MAXREC specifier in OPEN statement using gfortran
I have some Fortran code that used to work on a Silican Graphics machine using Unix.
It doesn't now. The problem code is as follows:
      open(unit=14,recl=185,file='fort.15',status='old',
     1      access='direct',maxrec=2606)

Error message is:
      1      access='direct',maxrec=2606)
                            1
Error: Syntax error in OPEN statement at (1)

I can change the order of the open statement to (for example):
      open(unit=14,file='fort.15',status='old',access='direct',
     1              recl=185,maxrec=2606)

and get the following error:
      1              recl=185,maxrec=2606)
                             1
Error: Syntax error in OPEN statement at (1)


maxrec= is not a standard part of Fortran. If you want to compile the code with gfortran you will need to work out what particular non-standard intention the author of the code had. Practically, just delete it.

Quoting from the Intel docs (inherited from Compaq and DEC), "The MAXREC specifier indicates the maximum number of records that can be transferred from or to a direct access file while the file is connected." I agree with @francescalus that it can safely be removed.
